# Extracting specific Values from a text (txt) file using Java Script (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, file, txt

I'm writing a webpage where you can upload text files and then do some analysis on the file.

the text file is formatted like this:

- 0 1   475
- 1 2   437
- 2 3   553
- 3 4   500
- 4 5   612
- 5 6   491
- 6 7   444
- 7 8   544
- 8 9   491
- 9 10  595

'*' is only used to make a list on stack-overflow not actually in the text file

I only need to extract the third column(three digits)
and place the values in a variable that I can later use for my analysis.

How can I do this? I can't seem to find an answer with the javascript.

thanks

Comment: What are you having problems with ? Accessing the file's content ? Processing the file's content ?

Comment: @Titus so basically I have created a drag-drop component and now when I upload the files I would like to process them as highlighted above. For example, after the file has uploaded, at the event of a button click, it can process the values of the file and store it into a variable and then later i can use these values for some computation. So what i need help with is processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it:

```js
document.querySelector('#fileInput').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  readFile(e.target.files[0]);
});

function readFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    const values = reader.result.split('\n').map(line => (+line.split(' ')[2]));
    console.log(values);
  };
}

const fileContent = `0 1 475
1 2 437
2 3 553
3 4 500
4 5 612
5 6 491
6 7 444
7 8 544
8 9 491
9 10 595`;

const blob = new Blob([fileContent], {type: 'text/plain'});
readFile(blob);
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="readFile(this.files[0])">
```

In this example I've used a `Blob` to imitate a file but you can also use the `<input type="file" />` to test the function with a real file.

What this does is to use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read a file as text and then parse the content of the file by creating an array that has each line of text in the file as an element (`reader.result.split('\n')`) and then mapping that array to only keep the last number. That is achieved by splitting the line on every white space character  and converting to a number and keeping only the third element from the resulting array (`+line.split(' ')[2]`, the `[2]` selects the third element and `+` converts that element to a `number`).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function transforms each string into an integer:

```js
const input = ["0 1 475",
               "1 2 437",
               "2 3 553",
               "3 4 500",
               "4 5 612",
               "5 6 491",
               "6 7 444",
               "7 8 544",
               "8 9 491",
               "9 10 595"];
const output = input.map((str) => parseInt(str.split(" ")[2]))
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But the problem is that the file values change every time a new file is uploaded so having constant values wouldn't work well. Is there another way to get over this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
   let str= `0 1 475
1 2 437
2 3 553
3 4 500
4 5 612
5 6 491
6 7 444
7 8 544
8 9 491
9 10 595`

let re=/\d{3}$/gm

console.log(str.match(re))
```